# To find out the default APN programmatically?

Tags: android, apn, access-point-name

i wish to find out the functionality for checking the default APN... i.e active APN on a handset .

Answer (score 1):

To return only selected APN use:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"), null, null, null, null);
```

To return the entire list of APN use:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current"), null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Then i try to query this content provider it returns this error `java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10928 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.`

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-05/msg03754.html

At least, it worked on my rooted G1 (T-Mobile US) and in the emulator (TelKila).

Comment: This link is not working anymore..can you give an updated link?